# How to do unlimited recursion in mysql?

Tags: mysql, recursion

I have a mysql stored procedure made it recursively, it always returned 499 rows max.
my stored procedure is moving in a tree (not a binary tree) and check the nodes if they have children and so on until it reached the leaves.

I don't know how can I convert my code into non-recursive way, I just want to ask for tow points:

- how can I make an infinite recursive in mysql(mysql server version is 5.5)?
- if that can't happened, how can I change my cod into non-recursive way?

  ```
  CREATE PROCEDURE `get_citations`(in _pub_id int(10),in _lvl int,citation_count int)
  BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  declare p_id,c_count int;
  declare _counter int default 1;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT pat_publn_id,cited_count from temp.a_citations 
  where pub_parent=_pub_id ;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


  insert into a_citations
  (pat_publn_id ,
      publn_nr ,
      publn_kind,
      publn_auth,
      publn_date,
      cited_pat_publn_id,
      cited_count,
      pub_lvl,
      pub_parent)
          (select p.pat_publn_id,p.publn_nr,p.publn_kind,p.publn_auth,p.publn_date,c.cited_pat_publn_id,
          (select count(*) as cnt FROM patstat1304.tls212_citation c2 where c2.cited_pat_publn_id=c.pat_publn_id) as cited_count,_lvl as pub_lvl,_pub_id as pub_parent
          from patstat1304.tls212_citation c,patstat1304.tls211_pat_publn p
          where c.pat_publn_id=p.pat_publn_id and c.cited_pat_publn_id=_pub_id);
  commit;

  OPEN cur1;
  read_loop: LOOP

   fetch cur1 into p_id,c_count;
  IF (c_count !=0) then       
          call get_citations( p_id,_lvl+1,c_count);
          commit;

  END if;
  IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;
  set _counter=_counter+1;

  if(_counter=citation_count) then
   LEAVE read_loop;
  end if;
  end loop;
  CLOSE cur1;

  END
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL can not execute stored procedures with a very deep nesting.

Very soon, error `ER_STACK_OVERRUN_NEED_MORE` will appear.

Increasing the thread stack to go further will not work either.

To change the recursive call to a non recursive one, consider something like this:

1) Create a table named publications_to_process, with the publication and search level.

2) To start the search, insert the original publication in this table, with level 1.

3) In a loop, fetch one publication, examine the citations, and add the publications listed in the publications_to_process, incrementing the level.

4) As a bonus, for cases like:

Pub_1 --> Pub_2 --> Pub_3, 
Pub_1 --> Pub_3

there is no need to add Pub_3 again to the search if it has been processed already.

In other words, the publications are more likely to be a directed graph that a tree.

5) Either make the table temporary, or consider adding a `PROCESSLIST_ID` column, so that different sessions (having a different `CONNECTION_ID()`) do not step on each other, when executing this search in parallel.